# Representing a Roughness texture with a 16 to one compression ratio using functions or Compression losslessly

Tags: compression, mapping, textures

I have a 4 by 4 texture of bits black and white texture and I want to use a lossless compression or Function to represent the Bits with less values accurately at least 16 to 1

Bit orientation

F[100][120]=1 function

That means compressed or Equation it must average 4bits

Here is an example function that takes low Additional bits due to constants which each take 1 bit and do the whole texture. It need to be for 60 bitwise Ops piecewise and max 16 functions for the whole texture(4bit). It must do the same.

```
    for (q=0;q<122880;q++){
    screen[122879-q]=((127-(((q>>10)%128)+Math.abs(((q%256)%128)-64)>>1))>>4)
    }
    for (q=0;q<122880;q++){
    screen[q]=(q>>8)%128+Math.abs(((q%256)%128)-64)>>1
    }
    Good Bumpy
    for (q=0;q<122880;q++){
    screen[q]=(((q>>8)%25+Math.abs(((q%256)%128)-64)>>1)^2)
    }
```

This is an attempt for a bumpy and terrain texture at 256*480

Comment: https://www.gamedev.net/topic/685524-mountainous-roughness-equation-to-texture/

Comment: Darktree
http://www.darksim.com/html/dt25_description.html
TexRD
http://www.texrd.com/
Texture Garden
http://texturegarden.com/

Comment: http://www.neilblevins.com/cg_education/procedural_noise/procedural_noise.html